# Button in WPF does not reactivate after loop

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

this is my version of a very simple inventory management system. One of the buttons (ButtonAddName_Click) is disabled as long as I am reading a txt file, and it should reactivate upon reaching EndOfStream. But it does not.

Could you help me out? I am new to C# and I do not find a way around it at the moment.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="OMD_Inventory_Management_System.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OMD_Inventory_Management_System"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="OMD Inventory Management System" Height="450" Width="800">
    
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="lstSample"/>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="lstBin"/>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" x:Name="lstSearch"/>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="lstAllData" 
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,0,0,0">
            <Label Content="Sample name:"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtSampleName"/>
            <Label Content="Storage bin:"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtStorageBin" />
            <Button x:Name="Button" Margin="0,10,0,0" 
                    Click="ButtonAddName_Click" 
                    Content="Add sample to storage"/>
            <Label Content="Search for sample or bin:"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtSearchForSample"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button2" Margin="0,10,0,0" 
                    Click="ButtonSearchName_Click"
                    Content="Search"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
    
namespace OMD_Inventory_Management_System
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private void ButtonAddName_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            lstSample.Items.Clear();
            lstBin.Items.Clear();
            lstAllData.Items.Clear();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSampleName.Text) 
                & !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtStorageBin.Text))
            {
                lstSample.Items.Add(txtSampleName.Text);
                lstBin.Items.Add(txtStorageBin.Text);
                lstAllData.Items.Clear();
                using (StreamWriter outputFile = File.AppendText("Inventory.txt"))
                {
                    outputFile.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t in \t{1}", 
                        lstSample.Items[0], lstBin.Items[0]));
                }
                string line;
                var file = new System.IO.StreamReader("Inventory.txt");
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    lstAllData.Items.Add(line);
                    if (line == null)
                    {
                        Button.IsEnabled = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Button.IsEnabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void ButtonSearchName_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            lstSearch.Items.Clear();
            int j = 0;
            string line;
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("Inventory.txt");
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSearchForSample.Text))
            {
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains(txtSearchForSample.Text))
                    {
                        lstSearch.Items.Add(line);
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: Your whole condition checks to see if ReadLine() is NOT null. Therefore, in the if condition line == null is never true and your button is never enabled.

Comment: I guess you misunderstand your problem. As far as I can tell, your button will be disabled in the interface only after your method completed, because you execute your whole batch of work on the UI thread. The problem of clicking the button again later probably doesn't occur because of parallel execution (your first execution should be finished already) but because you don't close your `file` after usage. Edit: part of this comment is related to the now-deleted answer...

Comment: Long story short: close your `file` instances after reading and re-evaluate your remaining problems afterwards.